# Conv1D with data_format channels_first yields error on Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to define a basic ConvNet using one Conv1D operation as follows:

```python
n_class = 10

# channels last (default)
input_shape = (100, 1)
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv1D(4, kernel_size=9, activation=activations.relu, padding='same')(inp)

x = MaxPool1D(pool_size=5)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```

and that works fine (which uses data_format='channels_last' as default). However, if, instead, I want to use data_format='channels_first':

```python
# "channels_first" inputs with shape (batch, channels, length).
input_shape = (1, 100)
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv1D(4, kernel_size=9, activation=activations.relu, data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(inp)

x = MaxPool1D(pool_size=5, data_format='channels_first')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```

I get the following error when defining the Conv1D layer:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/edward/Desktop/baselines/cnn_mel.py", line 720, in <module>
    model = get_1d_dummy_model(params_learn=params_learn, params_extract=params_extract)
  File "/Users/edward/Desktop/baselines/architectures.py", line 71, in get_1d_dummy_model
    x = Conv1D(4, kernel_size=9, activation=activations.relu, data_format='channels_first', padding='same')(inp)
  File "/Users/edward/miniconda3/envs/baseline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/edward/miniconda3/envs/baseline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 337, in __init__
    **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data_format'
```

Any insight as to what is being done wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are not using the most recent code (not just most recent release). For Conv1D layer, `data_format='channels_first'` is not supported even in the most recent release 2.1.6. You will need to clone and use codes from the master branch. The support is added by [this commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/027d37961afff8a7963836ca87ccdbbf65a78811) on 5/7/2018. The documentation is always synced to the master which can be confusing. [The idea (from the Keras creator François Chollet)](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/778126537824624641) is that

> versions only exist to force PyPI users to upgrade. They are not meaningful. You should be constantly synced to master.

You can find some old Keras documentation [here](https://github.com/faroit/keras-docs).